# Including documents in the emit compared to include_docs = true in CouchDB

Tags: couchdb

I ran across a mention somewhere that doing an `emit(key, doc)` will increase the amount of time an index takes to build (or something to that effect).

Is there any merit to it, and is there any reason not to just always do `emit(key, null)` and then `include_docs = true`?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Yes, it will increase the size of your index, because CouchDB effectively copies the entire document in those cases.  For cases in which you can, use `include_docs=true`.

There is, however, a race condition to be aware of when using this that is mentioned in the wiki.  It is possible, during the time between reading the view data and fetching the document, that said document has changed (or has been deleted, in which case `_deleted` will be `true`).  This is documented [here](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/HTTP_view_API) under "Querying Options".

Comment: perfect, thanks. i remember reading about the race condition, but the side effect of including the doc in the emit didn't occur to me until later.

Answer (score 4):

This is a classic time/space tradeoff.

Emitting document data into your index will increase the size of the index file on disk because CouchDB includes the emitted data directly into the index file. However, this means that, when querying your data, CouchDB can just stream the content directly from the index file on disk. This is obviously quite fast.

Relying instead on `include_docs=true` will decrease the size of your on-disk index, it's true. However, on querying, CouchDB must perform a document read for every returned row. This involves essentially random document lookups from the main data file, meaning that the cost and time of returning data increases significantly.

While the query time difference for small numbers of documents is slow, it will add up over every call made by the application. For me, therefore, emitting needed fields from a document into the index is usually the right call -- disk is cheap, user's attention spans less so. This is broadly similar to using covering indexes in a relational database, another widely echoed piece of advice.

I did a totally unscientific [test on this](https://dx13.co.uk/articles/2017/2/4/why-you-should-avoid-using-include_docs-in-cloudant-and-couchdb-view-queries.html) to get a feel for what the difference is. I found about an 8x increase in response time and 50% increase in CPU when using `include_docs=true` to read 100,000 documents from a view when compared to a view where the documents were emitted directly into the index itself.