# In CouchDB, how to get documents limited on value in related document? In terms of SQL, how to make WHERE on JOINed table

Tags: couchdb

Crossposting from user@couchdb.apache.org

Assume we have two kind of documents in CouchDB. Person and Car:

Person:

- _id
- firstname
- surname
- position
- salary

Car:

- _id
- person_id
- reg_number
- brand

So there is one to many relationship. One person can have many cars.

I can construct map function to get every person and his/her car next to each other. In such case key is array [person.id, 0] and [car.person_id, 1].

What I can't do, is limiting this view to owners of specific brand only, e.g. if I need salaries of owners of Ferrari.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you really need to have a car attached to more than one person, I'd think it'd be much easier to store the cars a person owns along with the person document as sub-objects. It would make the query much easier to write.

Comment: You are right, but it is not real life problem :) I just want to know if such query is possible in CouchDB?

Answer (score 2):

You might try something like this as your map function:

```
function(doc)
{
    if (doc.type == 'car')
    {
        emit(doc.brand, {'_id' : doc.person_id});
    }
}
```

Per the [CouchDB Wiki](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Introduction_to_CouchDB_views), as of version 0.11:

> If you emit an object value which has
>   `{'_id': XXX}` then `include_docs=true`
>   will fetch the document with id XXX
>   rather than the document which was
>   processed to emit the key/value pair.

This won't give you the salaries, per se, but you will get the person documents back which contain the salaries.

Note: For use of `include_docs=true`, [this post about a race condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1475307/including-documents-in-the-emit-vs-include-docs-true-for-couchdb) may be relevant.